# how to display simplecart.js items customised

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to display [simplecart.js](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/zipball/master) items in a custom formate. below code is displaying all the cart items in default formate.

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"> </div>
```

but i would like to display each item separately like

```
<div calss="item-name">Men's T-shirt</div>
<div calss="item-image">image</div>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the simplecartjs.org cart. The configuration is in the footer. You can use a function to create custom cart views. You can add this to the cart columns array.

```
{ view: function(item, column){
    return    item.get('name')+"<span class='item-format'>"+item.get('format')+"</span>";
}, attr: 'custom' }
```

Also this is discussed in the documentation here, http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/cart_columns

Source: [Github](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/issues/325)

Answer (score -1):

Try this........

```
<script>
var item_names = document.getElementsByClassName("itemName");
var arr = [].slice.call(item_names);
var genres = arr.map(function(el){
return el.innerHTML;
}).join(', ');
window.alert(genres);   
</script>
```